# why the nested sortable plugin not work in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this plugin
https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable in fiddle it out put is some thing like this 
http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/
But I insert that plugin in our fiddle it not work why ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3qtMt/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
            handle: 'div',
            items: 'li',
            toleranceElement: '> div'
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have any element of class `sortable` in the fiddle. You need to assign a class. Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/3qtMt/1/

```
<div class="sortabled">    
<div>
<ol class="sortable">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 5</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we apply this concept in this ubove fiddle

Comment: Yes we can. I don't know much about the nestedsortable but from the code, what I can understand is that you need "ol" instead of "ul" . And the nestedSortable should be called upon the list. I updated the code. Here is the link :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/ax34t/9/

Comment: Sir there is problem .When you expand "First level",and "menu_tc_2" it will not drop in "menu_tc_3"

Comment: please help last how we can make drag and drop

Comment: Expand First level (+ press button) .Expand "menu_tc_1".Then Drag "menu_tc_2" in "menu_tc_1_tc_2".i will not expand

Comment: can you please give other plugin if you have any know any nested tree view drag and drop

Comment: I think you can do this via jquery sortable. No need of any plugin. Just follow the steps mentioned in this link :http://a.shinynew.me/post/4641524290/jquery-ui-nested-sortables

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51668/discussion-between-user944513-and-kamlesh-kushwaha)